# Java: how do I change the color of a string?

Tags: java

I want to make some characters gray, and leave the rest black. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using Swing, AWT or what, to do the GUI work?

Comment: Currently, Just using a swing JTextArea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give more context, like James Black said. If you're talking about the console, check the bottom of my my post. If you're using Swing and a JLabel, for example:

```
JLabel title = new JLabel("Want a Raise?", JLabel.CENTER);
title.setForeground(Color.white);
```

Source: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/components/10labels/jlabel.html

It's really gonna depend on the context though.

**Edit**: Apparently you can, with [Enigma](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-12/02-qa-1220-console.html).

Answer (score 1):

Text color is typically part of the way it's output not the string it self. So as Mike said what context are you talking about? Is this the console, a GUI or a JSP page?

If you're talking about the console we would also need to know the platform. A Windows console is different then a Unix console. This source forge project looks like it could help
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcons/